# Import-Module with powershell from asp core website

Tags: azure, powershell, import-module

I´m currently trying to call an powershell application from my asp core application.

My first command is Import-Module to make sure that the correct module is loaded.

I tried several ways to do this:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        ps.AddCommand("Import-Module AzureRm").Invoke();
    }
```

This throws an CommandNotFoundException:

[CommandNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK0ip.png)

> The term 'Import-Module AzureRm' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again.

If I use AddScript instead I don´t get any feedback at all:

`var result =  ps.AddScript("Import-Module AzureRm").Invoke();`

Result is always returned as an empty object.

Is is even possible to use Import-Module in an ASP core application?

How do I get an result from AddScript and not an empty object?

Comment: I believe you will only receive something if the script in the AddScript method returns an object, in this case Import-Module does not. After importing the module what leads you to believe it is not imported?

Comment: I will try to force an output. When I try to use the module without importing it it throws an error that the azureRm term is not found. Which made me believe it might not be imported correctly.